# Errors are lost on a Prestashop redirection

Tags: php, authentication, module, smarty, prestashop

I write a module which use an API to create a user account on Prestashop.

The API use a button which call an url on my website. This URL execute a function on my module to create a user account.

If all the informations are Ok it works fine but my problem is when I have an error in the account creation.

I'd like to redirect the user to the authentication page and display the errors.

I tried this

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('account_error', $myErrors);
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication');
```

The redirection works but the errors seem to be lost.

Is there a way to redirect and keep the errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not show errors after redirection rather you should use your current controller and display errors there and use some button like "Fix errors" which upon clicking will take it to Auth page.
In your controller use

```
if (empty($email))
  $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Email is empty.');
```

and in your tpl use in top

```
{include file="$tpl_dir./errors.tpl"}
```